# Setting multiple Volumes to each Video tracks using AudioMixInputParameters AVFoundation is not working in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I am working on `Video` based `Application` in `Swift`. As per the requirement I have to select multiple `Videos` from `Device Gallery`, setting up different different `CIFilter` effects and `Volume` for each `Video Asset` and then merge all the `Videos` and have to Save the `Final Video`. As an output, when I will play the `Final Video` then `Video` sound `volume` should change accordingly.

I have already merged all the selected `Video Assets` into one with different different `CIFilter` effects but my problem is when I am trying to set `Volume` for each `Video Clips` then it's not working. I am getting the default `Volume` for my `Final Video`. Here is my code:

```
func addFilerEffectAndVolumeToIndividualVideoClip(_ assetURL: URL, video: VideoFileModel, completion : ((_ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?){

        let videoFilteredAsset = AVAsset(url: assetURL)

        print(videoFilteredAsset)
        createVideoComposition(myAsset: videoFilteredAsset, videos: video)

        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent("\(video.fileID)_\("FilterVideo").mov")

        let filePath = url.path
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        do {
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                print("FILE AVAILABLE")
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath:filePath)
            } else {
                print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
            }
        } catch _ {
        }

        let composition: AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        let compositionVideo: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
        let compositionAudioVideo: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())


        //Add video to the final record
        do {
            try compositionVideo.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoFilteredAsset.duration), of: videoFilteredAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch _ {
        }

        //Extract audio from the video and the music
        let audioMix: AVMutableAudioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
        var audioMixParam: [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters] = []

        let assetVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack = videoFilteredAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

        let videoParam: AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: assetVideoTrack)
        videoParam.trackID = compositionAudioVideo.trackID

        //Set final volume of the audio record and the music
        videoParam.setVolume(video.videoClipVolume, at: kCMTimeZero)

        //Add setting
        audioMixParam.append(videoParam)

        //Add audio on final record
        do {
            try compositionAudioVideo.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoFilteredAsset.duration), of: assetVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

        } catch _ {
            assertionFailure()
        }

        //Fading volume out for background music
        let durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoFilteredAsset.duration)

        let firstSecond = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1))
        let lastSecond = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationInSeconds-1, 1), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1))

        videoParam.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: 0, toEndVolume: video.videoClipVolume, timeRange: firstSecond)
        videoParam.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: video.videoClipVolume, toEndVolume: 0, timeRange: lastSecond)

        //Add parameter
        audioMix.inputParameters = audioMixParam

        // Export part, left for facility
        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoFilteredAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
        exporter.videoComposition = videoFilterComposition
        exporter.outputURL = url
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie

        exporter.audioMix = audioMix

        exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: { () -> Void in
            completion!(exporter, url)
        })

    }
```

After that again I am using a method to merge all the `Video Clips` using `AVAssetExportSession`, there I am not setting any `AudioMixInputParameters`.

`Note:` When I am setting up volume in final merging method using `AVAssetExportSession's` `AudioMixInputParameters`, then `Volume` is getting change for full `Video`.

My question: Is it possible to set multiple `volume` for each `Video Clips`. Please suggest. Thank you!

Comment: Did you find the fix for this issue yet? Have the same problem.

Comment: I have fixed this. Still you are facing this issue @nerowolfe?

Comment: Yeah, still have problems with that. Looks like volume is applying to both tracks. I am trying to set different volume for each track separately

Comment: Okay, Please check my answer @nerowolfe

Comment: I am using AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters setVolume method to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working solution for my question:

```
func addVolumeToIndividualVideoClip(_ assetURL: URL, video: VideoFileModel, completion : ((_ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?){

        //Create Asset from Url
        let filteredVideoAsset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: assetURL)

        video.fileID = String(video.videoID)

        //Get the path of App Document Directory
        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent("\(video.fileID)_\("FilterVideo").mov")

        let filePath = url.path
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        do {
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                print("FILE AVAILABLE")
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath:filePath)
            } else {
                print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
            }
        } catch _ {
        }


        let composition: AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        let compositionVideo: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
        let compositionAudioVideo: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())


        //Add video to the final record
        do {
             try compositionVideo.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, filteredVideoAsset.duration), of: filteredVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch _ {
        }

        //Extract audio from the video and the music
        let audioMix: AVMutableAudioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
        var audioMixParam: [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters] = []

        let assetVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack = filteredVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

        let videoParam: AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: assetVideoTrack)
        videoParam.trackID = compositionAudioVideo.trackID

        //Set final volume of the audio record and the music
        videoParam.setVolume(video.videoVolume, at: kCMTimeZero)

        //Add setting
        audioMixParam.append(videoParam)

        //Add audio on final record
        //First: the audio of the record and Second: the music
        do {
            try compositionAudioVideo.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, filteredVideoAsset.duration), of: assetVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch _ {
            assertionFailure()
        }

        //Fading volume out for background music
        let durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(filteredVideoAsset.duration)

        let firstSecond = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1))
        let lastSecond = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationInSeconds-1, 1), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1))

        videoParam.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: 0, toEndVolume: video.videoVolume, timeRange: firstSecond)
        videoParam.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: video.videoVolume, toEndVolume: 0, timeRange: lastSecond)

        //Add parameter
        audioMix.inputParameters = audioMixParam

        //Remove the previous temp video if exist
        let filemgr = FileManager.default
        do {
            if filemgr.fileExists(atPath: "\(video.fileID)_\("FilterVideo").mov") {
                try filemgr.removeItem(atPath: "\(video.fileID)_\("FilterVideo").mov")
            } else {
            }
        } catch _ {
        }

        //Exporte the final record’
        let exporter: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
        exporter.outputURL = url
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        exporter.audioMix = audioMix

        exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: { () -> Void in
            completion!(exporter, url)

           // self.saveVideoToLibrary(from: filePath)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found, that exporting an asset with preset of `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` doesn't have an impact on output volume. When I tried to use `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality`, volume change successfully applied.

I wish it is better documented somewhere :(

The working code:

```
// Assume we have:
let composition: AVMutableComposition
var inputParameters = [AVAudioMixInputParameters]()

// We add a track
let trackComposition = composition.addMutableTrack(...)

// Configure volume for this track
let inputParameter = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: trackComposition)
inputParameter.setVolume(desiredVolume, at: startTime)

// It works even without setting the `trackID`
// inputParameter.trackID = trackComposition.trackID

inputParameters.append(inputParameter)

// Apply gathered `inputParameters` before exporting
let audioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
audioMix.inputParameters = inputParameters

// I found it's not working, if using `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`,
// so try `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality` first
let export = AVAssetExportSession(..., presetName: AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality)
export.audioMix = audioMix
```

Tested this with multiple *assetTrack* insertions to the same *compositionTrack*, setting different volume for each insertion. Seems to be working.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Alexander, my volume part is working fine. But sometimes I am getting this issue while processing multiple videos. Can you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930602/avassetexportsession-avfoundationerrordomain-code-11800-the-operation-could-not